# how can I fix the problem to my permutation number problem?

Tags: c++, numbers

I need to create a function that determines the minimum steps of permutations to the right of number a so that it is equal to number b. My code gets this error: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all
control paths [-Wreturn-type]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int nrCif(int a)
{
    int nr = 0;
    while(a != 0){
        nr ++;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return nr;
}

int inversa(int a)
{
    int o = 0;
    while(a != 0){
        o = o * 10 + a % 10;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return o;
}

int circular(int a, int b)
{
    int ca = a, contor = 0;
    while(ca != b && contor <= nrCif(a)){
        int aux = ca % 10;
        if(aux == 0){
            ca = ca / 10;
            aux = ca % 10;
            contor ++;
        }
        else
            {
                ca = aux * pow(10, nrCif(a)) + inversa(inversa(ca) / pow(10, nrCif(a)));
                contor ++;
            }
        if(contor != nrCif(a))
            return - 1;
        return contor;
    }
}

int main()
{

    ///1

    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << circular(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried creating two additional functions one to determine how long is the number so I can use it to determine the power to 10, and another one for the reverse number, so that I am able to permute the digits of the number.

Comment: Return something in all control paths of the function in question.

Comment: One of your other problems will be this : `pow(10, nrCif(a)) + inversa(inversa(ca) / pow(10, nrCif(a)));` NEVER use pow in integer calculations you will get rounding errors. Create your own power function to get integer powers of 10 (it is not that hard)

Answer (score 1):

If the `while` loop in `circular()` is never entered, then control flows out of the function without returning a value. That's [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).